# NodeJS Multer `upload.fields` returns `undefined`

Tags: node.js, forms, multer

I am using NodeJS to host a webpage to upload 2 files,
The following code snippet USED to work, but for some reason `req.files` now returns undefined

Here is my NodeJS (this code needs 2 fields, and opens a file with the file path, and with that data, makes a stage.)

```js
router.post("/api/upload", upload.fields([{ name: 'data', maxCount: 1 }, { name: 'song', maxCount: 1 }]), function(req,res){
  console.log(req.files);
  data = req.files["data"][0];
  song = req.files["song"][0];
  path_data = "uploads/" + data.filename;
  path_song = "uploads/" + song.filename;
  console.log(data, path_data, song, path_song);
  
  makeStage(path_data, path_song, req, function(result) {
    res.send(toString(result));
  });
});
```

Here is the Multer Config:

```js
const multer = require('multer');
const storage = multer.diskStorage({
    destination: function(req, file, cb) {
        cb(null, 'uploads/')
    },
    filename: function(req, file, cb) {
        cb(null, file.fieldname + '-multer')
    }
});
const upload = multer({storage});
```

Here is the simplified HTML:

```js
<form action=/api/upload method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">

<label>Level Data</label>
<input type="file" name="data" accept=".txt">
<hr>
<label>Level Song</label>
<input type="file" name="song" accept=".mp3">
<hr>
<button type="submit">Upload</button>

</form>
```

Comment: What do you mean by _"returns undefined"_? Do you mean `upload.fields()` returns `undefined` instead of a middleware function or are you seeing `undefined` somewhere else?

Comment: FYI you'd be better off using `destination: 'uploads'` which will ensure Multer creates the directory if required. Using the callback function, you are required to create the directory manually. See https://github.com/expressjs/multer#diskstorage

Comment: What is `js-sub`? If you're using JavaScript to submit the form, please [edit] your question to include the relevant details

Comment: 1. `req.files` used to return a dictionnary with all of the files, but now returns `undefined` for some reason, 2. I'll try that code out, 3. JS-SUB was just some old code i forgot to change, thank you for reminding me of that